# VSTS Stack Used for Web App

Tags: azure-devops

What technology stack was used to build the VSTS web app?

I have searched long and wide without much clarity

Any info would be appreciated

Comment: Which technologies did you use to write the web app? (.Net, Angular etc.)

Comment: No, I am actually referring to the actual VSTS Website itself. I am wanting to know what tech stack was used to build it?

Answer (score 0):

In VSTS, you can create a build pipeline. A build pipeline is a representation of the automation process that you want to run to build and test your application. The automation process is defined as a collection of tasks. VSTS and TFS have a number of tasks to build and test your application. For example, tasks exist to build .Net, Java, Node, Android, Xcode, and C++ applications. You can also run command line, PowerShell, or Shell scripts in your automation.

Here are some examples for your reference:

- [Build your ASP.NET 4 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4?view=vsts&tabs=vsts)
- [Build your ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=vsts&tabs=designer)
- [Build your Node app with Gulp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/nodejs/build-gulp?view=vsts&tabs=gitvsts%2Cweb%2Cdeploy-windows)